# React - Dynamically add inputs without mutating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to dynamically add inputs when the user clicks the button to add a question.

Usually doing a controlled form is easy as your know what the field names are. But in this situation they are dynamic.

I've got a working solution but it mutates the state.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

JSX

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);
        this.addQuestion = this.addQuestion.bind(this);
        this.removeQuestion = this.removeQuestion.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            questions: []
        }
    }
    onChange(e, i) {
        this.state.questions[i] = e.target.value;

        this.setState({
            questions: this.state.questions
        })
    }
    handleForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const body = {
            questions: this.state.questions
        };

        axios.post('/api/pdfs/create', body)
            .then(() => axios.get('/api/pdfs/fetch', { responseType: 'blob' }))
            .then((res) => {
                const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                return saveAs(pdfBlob, 'questions.pdf');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response)
            });
    }
    addQuestion() {
        this.setState({
            questions: [...this.state.questions, '']
        });
    }
    removeQuestion(index) {
        this.setState({
            questions: this.state.questions.filter((question, i) => i !== index)
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.addQuestion}>Add Question</button>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleForm}>
                    {this.state.questions.map((question, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <input type="text" name={`question-${question}`} onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e, index)} />
                            <button type="button" onClick={() => this.removeQuestion(index)}>x</button>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Make a copy of `this.state.questions` before you insert the new value. Then you won't mutate the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the state only in your onChange call, and that can be fixed easily:

```
 onChange(e, i) {        
    this.setState({
        questions: this.state.questions.map((v, i2) => i === i2 ? e.target.value : v),
    });
}
```

(This won't change the functionality though, its just a "best practice improvement")